# Optimize ffmpeg stereo splitting and broadcasting

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I recieve an rtmp-input with a video and a stereo audio. I need to split audio and send two videos with the left channel and the right channel on different adresses. I have such a command:

```
ffmpeg  -r 25 -loop 1 -i background.png \
-rtbufsize 2000M -i rtmp://stereoinput \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]overlay[video];[video]split[video][video2];[1:a]channelsplit[aleft][aright]" \
-map [video] -map [aleft]  -c:v libx264 -minrate 1000k -maxrate 1500k -b:v 1300k -bufsize 1000k \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -g 100 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast \
-c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -y -f flv rtmp://out_left \
-map [video2] -map [aright] -c:v libx264 -minrate 1000k -maxrate 1500k -b:v 1300k -bufsize 1000k \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -g 100 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast \
-c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -y -f flv rtmp://out_right
```

But it performs slow: it outputs only 20 fps. I encode on azure VPS with a 4 GB RAM and 4 Cores and has never thought it could had a problem like this. It encodes one stream perfectly.

Do you have any ideas how to make it faster?
For,example I also don't like that I have to encode the same videostream twice. I can't afford two commands cause I have to see whole output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tee](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#tee) pseudo-muxer, which allows you to encode a stream once and reuse it multiple times.

```
ffmpeg  -r 25 -loop 1 -i background.png \
-rtbufsize 2000M -i rtmp://stereoinput \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]overlay[video];[1:a]channelsplit[aleft][aright]"
-map [video] -map [aleft] -map [aright] 
-c:v libx264 -minrate 1000k -maxrate 1500k -b:v 1300k -bufsize 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p
-r 25 -g 100 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -y 
-f tee "[f=flv:select=v,\'a:0\']rtmp://out_left|[f=flv:select=v,\'a:1\']rtmp://out_right"
```

The select expression in the tee muxer refers to the mapped output streams, so `a:1` means the 2nd mapped audio output stream and `v` means all mapped video output streams.

Comment: I've once tried to use tee in more simple way, just like `ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -c copy -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp:/out1|[f=flv]rtmp://out2" `
on Win it just says `Output file #0 does not contain any stream` even with `loglevel verbose`, on Ubuntu works, but.. For example youtube says it recieves stream, but it does not start a broadcasting, and other player on oter service shows only a black screen. Ffplay catch it successfully.

Comment: In that particular case, it depends on if the encoding is flv compliant. Did you try my command above?

Comment: Yes, I've tried and actually get no video, only sound.

Comment: I can, but there's a limit for comment lengt. Should I place a link for a photo?

Comment: Edit it into the Q or paste it at pastebin or similar. Don't make it an image, please.